# JFrame error actionperformed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, visibility

I want to set the visibility of frame 2 to false, but whenever I do that, I get an error. I read something about this and it said that I needed to make my method I private method, but I can't do that since my method is actionPerformed. Somebody got any ideas? Everything about my program works fine, but I can't make my frame disappear. I also tried disposing the frame, but that didn't work either...

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame2.setVisible(false);
                frame3 frame3 = new frame3();
                frame3.setVisible(true);    
            }
        });

        btnNewButton.setBounds(42, 72, 157, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Douzaines");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame3 frame3 = new frame3();
                frame2.setVisible(false);
                frame3.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: "*but whenever I do that, I get an error.*" Posting the error message(stack trace) would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a name clash: `frame3` is used for a class and a variable:

```
frame3 frame3 = new frame3();
```

If your class is named `frame3` I would rename it to `Frame3`.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it!